# Why / how are some c++ headers included by default in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In visual studio c++, some headers seems to be included by default.
For example, I can use `std::strncpy` or `std::string` without including `<string>` or `<cstring>`, but I cannot use `std::cout` or `std::min()` without including `<iostream>` or `<algorithm>`.

Then, when I want to compile the source code on unix with g++, I get compilation error if I forgot to add the includes that visual studio did not warm me about because of its implicit includes.

Where does the default includes come from in visual studio? Is there a way to deactivate this behavior for future and existing projects? Note: my visual studio projects are not using precompiled headers.

Comment: There is nothing in the standard that says a header can't include other headers in the standard library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio has no headers included by default. However, some headers include other headers, so if you include `<iostream>`, that may sometimes include `<string>` in some compilers, and many headers also include `<cstring>`. So you are including them yourself, by accident.

Which headers includes which other headers varies from library to library, so always explicitly include the headers used by that file.

Comment: Indeed, this is the case on msvs. However, why does the same code not compile with g++: `error: 'strncpy' is not a member of 'std'`. Are the headers different between g++ and msvs?

Comment: You need to `#include <cstring>` to get `strncpy`  it may, or may not be included by other headers in different C++ setups.

Comment: @Fehnryr The standard requires some headers to include other headers, but often a header includes other headers which aren't required by the standard. Therefore, you might observe different behaviors on different compilers. "Are the headers different between g++ and msvs?" - Yes, the C++ standard generally only specifies the public interface for the standard library. The implementation is left for the compilers.